# How to disable keyboard shortcut animation in Office 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking for a way to disable the animations for keyboard shortcut selection in Office 2013, especially Excel 2013. When you select a keyboard shortcut using Alt and a key sequence (e.g. Alt->H->O->H to change row height), each key-press causes an animation as the options become available. I use shortcuts **a lot** so this really takes up time.

I've disabled the typing and cell-movement animations through registry and disabled animations in Advanced System Settings, yet none of this has managed to stop the annoying shortcut animations. Any ideas, anybody? I'm desperate.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me:

> Windows Control Panel > Performance Information and Tools > Adjust Visual Effects

Uncheck the first option: Animate controls and elements inside windows.

Note however that disabling this will also disable any animations regarding Windows' buttons, scollbars, taskbar icons and popup windows, start button, copy dialog, etcetera.<sup>[[1]](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/39657-animate-controls-elements-inside-windows-off.html)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Disable Hardware Graphics Acceleration.

Excel > File > Options > Advanced.

Scroll down to the Display section and then enable the: *Disable Hardware Graphics Acceleration setting.*

If you have updated Office you can also look in:

Windows Control Panel > Performance Information and Tools > Adjust Visual Effects

Unclick the first option: *Animate controls and elements inside windows.*

Comment: I have the same issue as Raynard and tried the steps in this answer, but it made no difference, hence the down-vote.

Comment: This recently helped a client of mines and if you could  check the help docs for clarity on reasons to downvote. http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Fair enough - tried to remove the downvote, but my vote's locked in, apparently. :(