# How do I turn off insertion point animation in Microsoft Office 2016?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

The insertion point in Microsoft Office 2016 glides along as you type in a rather disconcerting manner:

[image]

This is rather distracting when you're trying to type. Is there a way to turn this animation off?

Answer (score 1):

From the question [How to disable keyboard shortcut animation in Office 2013?](https://superuser.com/questions/604215/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcut-animation-in-office-2013) I found a setting which you can set to turn off various animations in all applications, including the insertion point animation.

1. Go to `Windows Control Panel > Performance Information and Tools > Adjust Visual Effects`
2. Uncheck the first option, `Animate controls and elements inside windows.`
   [image: Windows 10 "Performance Options" dialog]