# OS X - How to disable the Office 2016 typing animation

Tags: macos, microsoft-office-2016

Basically, I am posing the same question as in this question - [How do I turn off insertion point animation in Microsoft Office 2016?](https://superuser.com/questions/1010738/how-do-i-turn-off-insertion-point-animation-in-microsoft-office-2016) -  but related to the Mac OS X version of office 2016.

The insertion point in Microsoft Office 2016 glides along as you type in a way that becomes very delayed when you type faster than 80 WPM:

[image]

This is rather distracting when you're trying to type. Is there a way to turn this animation off on OS X?

Comment: The cursor, you mean?

Comment: Yes, in essence the delay in the cursor is my issue

Comment: I'm not expert here, but I'd check your CPU usage when it happens - if it's high then there might be a conflict. Barring that, you could try removing and reinstalling office 2016 - my cursor doesn't lag, but with office 2013 I had to remove and reinstall like twice before it worked as well as I needed.

Comment: That being said, maybe [adjusting the blink rate](https://www.macissues.com/2014/12/08/how-to-change-your-macs-text-cursor-blink-rate/) would help. I've never done that and I'm not vouching for the process on that page - just an idea

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks for the suggestions, but this is not helping. I will keep searching for a possible solution. If I find anything, I will post the answer here for others to find.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the lag issue in both MS Word and Outlook,I weent to System Preferences>keyboard>import sources. On the left was A US Flag and Grammerian, which I had experimented with, but not purchased. I eliminated Grammarian, and voila, the lag time ended in Word and Outlook. I have a Mac laptop and was not having the lag there in these program, but that was because I had not used Grammarian on it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the the questioner is using Grammarian?